# Aws loadbalancer to nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We have ec2 machine `abc` with nginx configuration and our application can be accessed using `loadbalancer/mi` url.

Now there is new requirement to deploy another component along with already running component in abc machine. But it should not impact existing application.

So we cloned `abc` machine into `xyz` which mapped into same loadbalancer and it can be redirected using `loadbalancer/onboarding/mi`. For that i created new listerner rule and target group and added nginx configuration(in xyz machine) `rewrite ^/onboarding/ /;`

After this change, its returning 308 for `curl -sI localhost/mi`, 200 for `curl -sI localhost/onboarding/mi` if i try from machine `xyz`. And its returning 502 bad gateway for `loadbalancer/onboarding/mi` url.

Can someone help whats wrong and how i access application from xyz?

Comment: i dont know if this could be helpfull but i have done something similar to this few days ago
i have two web app on the same elastic beanstalk each one listening to individual ports, i have added two listeners to my loadBalancer and it works fine

Comment: It would help if you added your nginx config